# Encoded Dreams Cipher

Tags: cipher

This note was found at the scene of a Parisian artists loft in the 1960's.
 
Sadly, he committed suicide the day before his first major exhibition.

Can anyone decrypt his final written words? 
(It is believed to be a poem - written in English)

[image: Dreams Cipher]

Good luck

Hint 1:

> The numbers 129 & 36 may be useful to finding the solution.

As requested, see below transcription.

```
352430273121
161414242718
292128163124
183631271829
212816273629
303631293616
212318243229
26836263329
272336182714
352114252126
26241431304

352430273121
161414242718
292128163124
18835292627
182921281633
243036312936
162123211818
292631293027
31182422926
83614351626
248
```

Comment: Definitely not written by a Parisian artist. French people don't write their 1s like that :-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ciphertext:

> Hold fast to dreams / For if dreams die / Life is a broken-winged bird / That cannot fly.
>  Hold fast to dreams / For when dreams go / Life is a barren field / Frozen with snow.
>  (Langston Hughes, *Dreams*)

Cipher:

> A numerical substitution that uses two-digit groups for most letters, with the exception of `WXYZ` which each use a single digit. The substitution is derived from a 4x10 grid in which the letters of the alphabet were written in order along a path, skipping over every other grid cell.

Alphabet construction:

> [image: Alphabet grid substitution and its construction]

Solve path:

> I recognized a two-digit substitution from experience. I found the single digits that broke up the two-digit rhythm and inserted `1` before each of them. I replaced each unique two-digit group with a placeholder letter, and used the substitution solver [Quipqiup](https://quipqiup.com/) on the placeholder text to obtain the deciphered plaintext. With a mostly-correct plaintext in hand, I worked out the substitution key and the true nature of the single digits that broke the rhythm.

Comment: Brilliant! Your answer is absolutely correct. Thanks for solving. I often wondered if someone would find it. Well done!